# What should be the image dimension for publication?

Tags: r, image, tiff, journal

I need to export images from R for publication in a journal. I found the  `tiff()` function for this useful. I need atleast 300 dpi images. What should be the `height`, `width` and `unit` be set as?

I usually use `height = 10`, `width = 10`, `units = "in"`, `res = 300` and the images produced are good for on screen visualisation but I am not sure if they are suitable for publication in A4 pages. Reducing the `height` and `width` overlaps the text in the plots.

Comment: You should check the section containing instructions for the submission of the journal of your interest. Most of the time, they have a dedicated section to Figures (including images characteristics)

Comment: A4 is 8.3"x11.7" so 10" is not ideal.